# Apps Script - Invalid scope error for send email

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Apps Script that interacts with Google Drive and sends an email. The scopes under the project properties shows the following required scopes.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

I am trying to generate the refresh token in the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). When I provide **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail** as one of the scopes it errors out saying that it is an invalid scope.

Comment: I'm not seeing that as a scope under Drive or Gmail.

Comment: Hi Mithun. I tried to replicate your scenario -- Going to the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), added `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail` in the *Input your own scopes* section, then clicked on Authorize APIs. It worked properly. Could you post more details? Specifically, step-by-step (screenshots would help) actions you've taken?